# How to approach REST API path parameter versioning?

Tags: rest, request, get, path-parameter

### Question

I'm trying to figure out what would be the best approach on path parameter versioning, but haven't been able to find a good/trustful source.

Say you have two entities `category` and `product` and the following REST endpoint to obtain the products within a given category reference.

```
GET /categories/{categoryReference}/products
```

You entity has a legacy `categoryReference` which needs to be supported as well, what would be the best approach. I've got two approaches on my mind. What would be the best way of doing it and why? (if there's other way, please feel free to add it).

### Option 1: New Endpoint

Given that you have a "new" parameter the endpoint should be new:

```
GET /categories/oldCatRef/{oldCategoryReference}/products
```

### Option 2: A query param

Given that you are modifying the query by filtering with a *different* param:

```
GET /categories/{oldCategoryReference}/products?usingOldCatRef=true
```

Comment: Is there going to be any ambiguity, for a given value, whether it's an old or new reference? If not, maybe just accept _either_ as the path parameter.

Comment: Yup there could be ambiguity, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, all you have to do is to use the a single endpoint as follows

```
GET /categoryProducts
```

And then, in the **body**, you accept both values in a JSON, taking into account which of thosr have prelation (my advice is to use the new one). If you receive one or the other you will have the business logic in the controller:

```
{
  "categoryRef" : "new",
  "oldCategoryRef" : "old"
}
```

No need to use path parameters or query params in this query.